# Facing problems while installing Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

These errors are showing while installing Visual Studio Code.

```
dell@Mittal:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i "code_1.24.1-1528912196_amd64(1).deb"
Selecting previously unselected package code.
(Reading database ... 268063 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack code_1.24.1-1528912196_amd64(1).deb ...
Unpacking code (1.24.1-1528912196) ...
Setting up code (1.24.1-1528912196) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/code.postinst: line 70: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package code (--install):
 installed code package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d && sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
sudo dpkg -i "code_1.24.1-1528912196_amd64(1).deb"
```